# How to separate and drag one of the taskbar buttons for the same app which has several instances running?

Tags: windows-11

I have several instances of the same app running. I already have the "combine taskbar buttons" set to 'Never'. When I drag one of the instances' taskbar buttons, it drags along all the other instances buttons along. In Windows 10 I used '7+ Taskbar Tweaker' app to separate them. This app doesn't support Windows 11 and the feature looks like is not yet implemented in Windhawk.

Is there a way to separate the buttons?

Comment: Did you try with Explorer Patcher? https://ramensoftware.com/7-taskbar-tweaker-on-windows-11-with-windows-10s-taskbar

Comment: It didn't work. I am also using StartAllBack and the two don't seem to play very well together.

Comment: "Not yet implemented in Windhawk" - are you sure? https://windhawk.net/mods/taskbar-grouping

Answer (score 0):

I am using the beta version of 7+ Taskbar Tweaker which works in Windows 11 and the old taskbar. I am using StartAllBack app and it looks like it restores the old taskbar which is compatible with the beta version.
(beta as of today, version v5.14.1.1)

https://ramensoftware.com/7-taskbar-tweaker#download